# Installing Xcode 6.4 on El Capitan parallel with Xcode 7 installed

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator, osx-elcapitan

I have a need in both versions of Xcode's - I do support/development for project on Swift 1.2 (and it is too big to port it right now to Swift 2.0) and I need to develop on Swift 2.0 for other project. 
I used to have Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7 beta and that was fine. Hoverer with Xcode 7 GM release thing got complicated as app bundle name isn't "Xcode Beta" anymore.

I installed Xcode 7 on top of Xcode 6 (it was a week ago, so I'm not 100% sure in that but I believe I overwrite Xcode 6.4). Then I downloaded Xcode 6.4 from developer.apple.com and installed it into /Applications/Xcode6/Xcode

- When I run it - it doesn't have any simulators.
- `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode6/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/` doesn't help
  I can't install simulators in *Window->Devices* - Xcode just freeze on the process of installing.
- Tried to run Simulator via *Xcode->Other Developer Tool->Simulator* - simulator freeze on the start (icon keep "jumping" in the dock).

Do you have any idea how I can fix that apart from installing 10.10 on separate partition

**Note:** I'm aware that I won't be able to submit apps from 10.11. We have a build server, I just need a way to debug current code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two primary causes for this behavior that I have observed.

You may be hitting an issue caused by trying to run both at the same time.  Please make sure you fully quit Xcode 7, its Simulator.app, its Instruments.app, etc before running anything from within Xcode 6.4.

Also, if you ran Xcode 6.4 from /Applications/Xcode.app previously during this boot, you will need to reboot due to having changed its location.  This issue with renaming Xcode.app was is mostly fixed in Xcode 7.0 (there are a few minor followup fixes in the 7.1 beta).

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't running any Xcode 7 apps but I did reboot last time a week ago or so. And reboot did actually fixed the issue.